# SQL Comparing a value with two values in another table to return a value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get a value from a table by comparing a value to two other values.

I have a table like

```
        Employee  
EmployeeID       Salary  
001---------------10  
002---------------25
```

...
And a table like

```
         Salary  
LevelNo LowerLimit UpperLimit  
1--------01---------15  
2--------16---------30
```

I need to take the salary from the Employee table and display the level number. I can get the lowest to display but not the rest. I am new to this so any help is greatly appreciated. This is my code so far using Sqlite3:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Salary, LevelNO  
FROM Employee_T, SalaryLevel_T  
WHERE LevelNO = (Salary < UpperLimit AND Salary > LowerLimit);
```

This only displays one `EmployeeID`, `Salary`, and `LevelNO` and it's the lowest.

Comment: Just leaver the `LevelNo =` out of your `WHERE` clause and you are pretty close.  You then need `<=` and `>=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.Salary, s.LevelNO
FROM Employee_T e
JOIN SalaryLevel_T s ON e.Salary between s.LowerLimit and s.UpperLimit
```

If you don't want to use `between` you can do

```
JOIN SalaryLevel_T s ON e.Salary >= s.LowerLimit and e.Salary <= s.UpperLimit
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to look up the information on between. That worked though!

Comment: `X between A and B` is the same as `X>= A and X<=B`